# "Dirty" polygons created when using "Merge selected features" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

When I selecting features to merge in QGIS 2.14.3-Essen using "merge selected features", I sometimes get "dirty" results with redundant polygon vertices. Is there an ex-ante or an ex-post way to get rid of them? Using Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Those vertices aren't redundant, they're there because your input polygons don't share the exact same border. You'd get the same result merging them in another GIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those gaps are produced because during the digitizing process the "topological" option is not enabled. Hence borders must be redrawn instead of being used as a reference for the new polygon.

There is a simple and quick approach to solve the problem. Here is a demonstration with a polygon layer with the same issues:

1) First the original shapefile, with Chilean administrative regions.

[image]

2) After enabling editing mode and merge two regions gaps appear.

[image]

[image]

3) In editing mode again you could use the 'Node Tool' in order to select the vertices of those gaps.

[image]

[image]

4) Finally, press Supr to delete the vertices and consequently the gaps.

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issues, thanks so much for explaining.

Comment: Great! If it was helpful, you could accept the answer using the tick symbol.